# Общий элемент двух массивов

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется два массива (вектора, разницы нет какой контейнер использовать) нужно найти два элемента, которые есть и в первом и во втором. Кроме идей про *перебор* всех чисел ничего не придумал.

> Можно конечно использовать *lower_bound* для оптимизации

Но я нуждаюсь в быстром ответе на запрос (константным в лучшем случаем, потому что массивов у меня может быть много и запросов тоже, около *1000*).

Как это можно сделать **?** возможно есть какой-то алгоритм решающий эту проблему.

Comment: Сортировка + проход в поисках совпадения. O(N lg N) из-за сортировки. Если возможна та же сортировка подсчетом - O(N). Можно попробовать приспособить фильтр Блума, конечно, но тогда не будет точно известен элемент + возможны ложные срабатывания.

Comment: Для ускорения можно подключить многопоточность.

Comment: Вместо сортировки можно свалить массив в std:set или в std::unordered_set, и пройтись поиском по второму... по факту эквивалентно предложению Harry, но с хешем сложность будет близка к O(N).

Comment: Для того, чтобы говорить о множественной задаче, надо знать, какая часть остается неизменноой, а какая меняется. В любом случае, ни о каком константном времени не может быть и речи.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> res;
vector<int>  fv{1, 4, 5, 9, 23, 12, 24, 45, 56, 75};
vector<int>  sv {3, 6, 7, 23, 11, 12, 34, 46, 8, 19};
set_intersection(fv.begin(), fv.end(), sv.begin(), sv.end(), back_inserter(res));
    // элементы вектора res
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не могу добавлять комментариев. А std::set_intersection не поможет ?
Если массива только только два, то вычислив пересечение и положив его в хэш таблицу (std::unordered_set), для каждого запроса будет почти O(N)

Comment: `std::set_intersection` требует отсортированных массивов на входе.

Comment: Верно. Но это вроде и в документации написано, вы это к чему ?
Если про O(N), то я имел в виду сложность запроса, исключая предпосчёт( сортировку двух массивов). Причём N - размер пересечения, а не исходных массивов

Comment: К тому, что в данной задача массивы не упорядочены. Соответственно в любом решении, требующем сортированности, необходимо принимать во внимание затраты на сортировку.